# How do I use SQL to return an average value for a day in a date range?

Tags: sql, blockchain, ethereum, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to query the public Ethereum blockchain for gas data. I want my query to return the average amount of gas consumed per transaction over the course of a day, for each day since the blockchain went public to present day.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT receipt_gas_used, block_timestamp, block_number
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.transactions`
WHERE DATE(block_timestamp) BETWEEN "2015-07-30" AND "2021-05-10"
LIMIT 2200
```

When I wrap the `receipt_gas_used` in the `AVG` function, I only get on result. When I run the query as shown above, I get numerous results for the same day. How can I write this function so that I get an average per day?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT DATE(block_timestamp) as date, AVG(receipt_gas_used)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.transactions`
WHERE DATE(block_timestamp) BETWEEN '2015-07-30' AND '2021-05-10'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

You probably don't need the `WHERE` clause, but I left it in.

Comment: I think this is the quickest I've ever gotten an accurate answer from Stack Overflow...So quick that I can't mark this answer as correct for another 8 minutes.

Comment: here's a public query with the data: https://luabase.com/run/662c231eda384319b3a73478e63de23e